# can someone watch my facebook video chats from a computer im still logged in on?

Tags: facebook, account-security

can someone watch my facebook video chats from a computer im still logged in on?
Say i video chat with someone and my facebook is open on a third device, can that third device watch the video im receiving?

Comment: if the camera is on and pointed at the computer you are chatting on, then yes

Comment: Are you sure? I don't think it connects your video to all of your logged in sessions. Only the one in which you accept the call on. You can't simply watch the call from your laptop if you are chatting via the iPhone app for example.

Answer (score 1):

No. The video is end to end.  All devices would 'ring' but video is only made to the one that 'answers'.

Comment: It would be great if you provided some references to that.

Comment: I will see if I can record a video of my test. I can see when I test it that their is a connection between me and the caller on netstat. My other device (laptop) which was logged in to Facebook 'rang' but once the call was accepted my other device could not see the video and their was indeed no connection to the originating caller.  The OP wanted to know if the other device could see the video that was ongoing. I can conclude it does not.

Comment: Most streaming (voice call / video stream) is p2p, it would be very inefficient to implement it otherwise. Even if multicasting would be widely adopted, it's unreasonable to bombard uninterested clients with data. However this question can not be answered without examining FB's chat API thoroughly. It **might** be possible to request another stream (even unnoticed) by a capable person. Without API validation the answer should be "probably not" or "not in an easy way".